# Booting Ubuntu 20.04 DVD on Athlon 64 results in Grub unknown filesystem error

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, dvd

dug up an old PC (Athlon 64 x2 4400+) I built many years ago and want to see if it runs a "recent" version of Linux ideally Ubuntu. However booting from DVD I get Grub unknown filesystem error. In contrast it boots Fedora 36 dvd and seems to work relatively well.

Any thoughts on why the different behaviour?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Thanks I will work through it